# My Cocos2dx game disrupts sounds of other sound-focused apps in iPhone

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

I've used CocosDenshion to play sound in my game. This is the code I used to load sound

```
CocosDenshion::SimpleAudioEngine::sharedEngine()->preloadEffect("sounds/tile_move.mp3");
```

and I've played sounds like this:

```
CocosDenshion::SimpleAudioEngine::sharedEngine()->playEffect("sounds/tile_move.mp3", 0);
```

When I tried to listen to a podcast app, and played my game It disrupts the podcast. Even when I mute sound from my game using this code:

```
CocosDenshion::SimpleAudioEngine::sharedEngine()->setEffectsVolume(0.0f);
```

The podcast sound still disrupts.
Can anyone help me with this problem?
Regards.

Comment: Perhaps related, perhaps not: playing effects as .mp3 files is wasteful. MP3 is a streaming format suitable for background music. iOS devices can only decode one MP3 in hardware, all others played in parallel have to be decoded by the CPU. Use .wav or .caf for short-lived effects and playBackgroundMusic to play mp3 music.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any chance that I turned Background Modes on, but Not checked Audio and Airplay button on and it caused the problem?

Comment: AFAIK there should be a flag where you can test whether "iPod music" is playing. ObjectAL has such a flag for example, and it works by enabling it and then ObjectAL will not play sound **if** background music was playing at the start of the app. I only know it was a recurring issue with CocosDenshion in cocos2d-iphone that it either didn't have this flag or it didn't work or it just reported that music was on but wouldn't prevent you from doing things that would stop background music.